# Changing hyperlink color without overriding font

Tags: html

I'm currently using this ccs:

```
    /* A Free Design by Bryant Smith (bryantsmith.com) */

html, body {
text-align: center;
}
p {text-align: left;}


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #333333 url(images/img01.gif) repeat-x;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666666;
    background-color:#252F33;
}
*
{
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 text-align:left;}

#header {
    position:relative;
    width: 680px;
    height:99px;
    margin-left:29px;
    margin-right:21px;
    background: url(header.png) no-repeat;
}

#page
{
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
  display: table; 
  height: 100%;  
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  background: #252F33 url(background.png) repeat-y;
  width: 730px;
}


.title
{
position:relative;
left:30px;
top:22px;
text-align:left;
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:32px;
font-weight:normal;
color:#252F33;
}

.subText
{
position:relative;
left:62px;
top:26px;
text-align:left;
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#CEEAEE;
}


.articleTitle
{
text-align:left;
padding-left:25px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
color: #2C4969;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:24px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.articleContent
{
width:auto;
position:relative;
padding-left:50px;
padding-right:75px;
color:#101214;
text-align:left;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:18px;
}

.rightLinks
{
width: 102px;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:21px;
height:auto;
margin-right:-3px;
background-image:url(links_branch.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-align:right;
float:right;
}

.rightLinks a:hover
{
color:#667765;
}



.rightLinks .linkTitle
{
font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;
margin-top:27px;
margin-bottom:32px;
margin-right:5px;
}


#bar
{
    position:relative;
    width: 680px;
    height:57px;
    margin-left:29px;
    margin-right:21px;
    background: url(bar.png) no-repeat;
}

.menuLink
{
    height:36px;
    width: 120px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    font-family:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#252F33;
    padding-top:19px;
}

.menuLink:hover
{
    background: url(bar2.png) repeat-x;
}

a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#252F33;
}

#pageContent
{
width: 680px;
height:500px;
}

#footer {

    width: 730px;
    height:60px;
    background: url(footer.png) no-repeat;
text-align:center;
font-size:10px;
color:#667765;
padding-top:34px;
}

#footer a
{
font-size:10px;
color:#667765;
}

html, body {
text-align: center;
}
p {text-align: left;}
```

and I want to change the hyperlink color. I tried the advice here: http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/link-colours.shtml of including this code:

```
 <style type="text/css">
<!--
a:link {color: #000000; text-decoration: underline; }
a:active {color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline; }
a:visited {color: #008000; text-decoration: underline; }
a:hover {color: #ff0000; text-decoration: none; }
-->
</style>
```

but including the code changed both the font and the margins. How can I alter the css that I'm using so as to alter the hyperlink color without altering the font or margins?

Comment: There is nothing in the second snippet that would change fonts or margins... did you add anything further? Where did you add it?

Comment: Off-topic, but the CSS shown here is a complete mess.

Comment: Thanks Eamonn. No, I didn't add anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can offer you is a sort-of answer, as there is nothing in the provided material that would affect your text in the manner described. I can however provide some cleaned up CSS.

```
/*BASIC STRUCTURE*/
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align:left;
    color: #666;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #333 url(images/img01.gif) repeat-x;
    background-color:#252F33;
}

/*TYPOGRAPHY*/
a {
    outline: none;
    color: #000;
}

a:active {
    color: #0000ff;
}

a:visited {
    color: #008000;
}

a:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}

/*SECTIONS*/
#header {
    width: 680px;
    height:99px;
    margin: 0 21px 0 29px;
    background: url(header.png) no-repeat;
}

... etc
```

There are a few things to note about the CSS above, which I'll go through as I assume you are at a beginner-level (excuse me if not!).

First of all, note that I have absorbed your second snippet into the original CSS file, which is where pretty much any and all of your CSS should be. The snippet you provided for styling your links looked like something placed in the `<head>`section of your HTML. While this does work, it is not ideal for working on your project in the future - keep all the CSS rules in one place, and in the order of [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) required.

Next, note how the `text-align`rule is now only mentioned once, as part of the `html, body` rule. Again, this comes down to specificity but basically once I have declared that everything in my HTML and page body should be `text-align: left`, then there is no need to repeat that in any other rule unless I wish to change it (`text-align: right`). This applies to all CSS, it's where the 'Cascading' part comes from. If a rule is there simply to repeat an already defined style (eg. your `p` rule), then you can get rid of it.

Default stylings need not be mentioned - links default to `text-decoration: underline` on most browsers, so no real need to specify it unless you are changing it.

The Universal Selector (the `*` rule) is a powerful beast, and should be handled with care. Basically, any rule you put here will try to apply itself to *every element on the screen*. Use it to [declare default styles or rules only](http://css-tricks.com/things-it-might-be-funuseful-to-try-the-universal-selector-on/). I have included `position: relative` as an example. Using it to delcare everything be centered within its parent element (`margin: 0 auto;`) *may* be unwise.

You might also look into placing a browser reset at the top of your code. This removes any styling applied to elements by various browsers and gives you 100% control over how your page looks. One of the most popular is the reset by [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Lastly, see how I have broken up even this small amount of CSS into chunks? This gives your CSS **much** more structure and hence is much easier to read and code. I commonly use chunks like Basic Structure, Typography, Header, Elements, Footer, and use `@import` for my reset. I also use [CSS shorthand](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200502/efficient_css_with_shorthand_properties/) where possible, also aiding readability.

As for your exact problem, clean up your CSS file, put all your CSS in one place, remove duplicated rules, understand and decide exactly what each `text-` or `font-` or `margin` rule is supposed to be doing, and you will probably arrive at the solution.

And read up on specificity.